# Cannot destruture property linerGradiant of r as it is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I get `Cannot destruture property` linerGradiant`of`r `as it is undefined` during runtime (not build time) so it's hard to debug. Issue is from compiled js file, which is difficult to read

fn is defined:

```
function linearGradient(color, colorState, angle = 195) {
  return `linear-gradient(${angle}deg, ${color}, ${colorState})`;
}

export default linearGradient;
```

I use it here:
BoxRoot.tsx

```
export default styled(Box)(({ theme, ownerState }) => {
  const { palette, functions, borders, boxShadows } = theme;
  const {
    variant,
    bgColor,
    color,
    opacity,
    borderRadius,
    shadow,
    coloredShadow,
  } = ownerState;

  const { gradients, grey, white } = palette;
  const { linearGradient } = functions;
  const { borderRadius: radius } = borders;
  const { colored } = boxShadows;
 if (variant === "gradient") {
    backgroundValue = validGradients.find((el) => el === bgColor)
      ? linearGradient(gradients[bgColor].main, gradients[bgColor].state)
      : white.main;
  } else if (validColors.find((el) => el === bgColor)) {
    backgroundValue = palette[bgColor]
      ? palette[bgColor].main
      : greyColors[bgColor];
  } else {
    backgroundValue = bgColor;
  }

  return {
    opacity,
    background: backgroundValue,
    color: colorValue,
    borderRadius: borderRadiusValue,
    boxShadow: boxShadowValue,
  };
});
```

And I call BoxRoot here:
Box.tsx

```
    <BoxRoot
      ref={ref}
      ownerState={{
        variant,
        bgColor,
        color,
        opacity,
        borderRadius,
        shadow,
        coloredShadow,
      }}
    />
```

I don't understand what is wrong and how to fix it.

Update 1 :
value of theme:

```
{"breakpoints":{"keys":["xs","sm","md","lg","xl"],"values":{"xs":0,"sm":600,"md":900,"lg":1200,"xl":1536},"unit":"px"},"direction":"ltr","components":{},"palette":{"mode":"light","background":{"default":"#f4f6f8","paper":"#ffffff"},"primary":{"contrastText":"#ffffff","main":"#5664d2","light":"rgb(119, 131, 219)","dark":"rgb(60, 70, 147)"},"text":{"primary":"#172b4d","secondary":"#6b778c","disabled":"rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.38)"},"common":{"black":"#000","white":"#fff"},"secondary":{"main":"#9c27b0","light":"#ba68c8","dark":"#7b1fa2","contrastText":"#fff"},"error":{"main":"#d32f2f","light":"#ef5350","dark":"#c62828","contrastText":"#fff"},"warning":{"main":"#ed6c02","light":"#ff9800","dark":"#e65100","contrastText":"#fff"},"info":{"main":"#0288d1","light":"#03a9f4","dark":"#01579b","contrastText":"#fff"},"success":{"main":"#2e7d32","light":"#4caf50","dark":"#1b5e20","contrastText":"#fff"},"grey":{"50":"#fafafa","100":"#f5f5f5","200":"#eeeeee","300":"#e0e0e0","400":"#bdbdbd","500":"#9e9e9e","600":"#757575","700":"#616161","800":"#424242","900":"#212121","A100":"#f5f5f5","A200":"#eeeeee","A400":"#bdbdbd","A700":"#616161"},"contrastThreshold":3,"tonalOffset":0.2,"divider":"rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12)","action":{"active":"rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.54)","hover":"rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.04)","hoverOpacity":0.04,"selected":"rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08)","selectedOpacity":0.08,"disabled":"rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26)","disabledBackground":"rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12)","disabledOpacity":0.38,"focus":"rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12)","focusOpacity":0.12,"activatedOpacity":0.12}},"shape":{"borderRadius":4},"shadows":["none","0 0 0 1px rgba(63,63,68,0.05), 0 1px 2px 0 rgba(63,63,68,0.15)","0 0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.31), 0 2px 2px -2px rgba(0,0,0,0.25)","0 0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.31), 0 3px 4px -2px rgba(0,0,0,0.25)","0 0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.31), 0 3px 4px -2px rgba(0,0,0,0.25)","0 0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.31), 0 4px 6px -2px rgba(0,0,0,0.25)","0 0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.31), 0 4px 6px -2px rgba(0,0,0,0.25)","0 0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.31), 0 4px 8px -2px rgba(0,0,0,0.25)","0 0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.31), 0 5px 8px -2px rgba(0,0,0,0.25)","0 0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.31), 0 6px 12px -4px rgba(0,0,0,0.25)","0 0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.31), 0 7px 12px -4px rgba(0,0,0,0.25)","0 0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.31), 0 6px 16px -4px rgba(0,0,0,0.25)","0 0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.31), 0 7px 16px -4px rgba(0,0,0,0.25)","0 0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.31), 0 8px 18px -8px rgba(0,0,0,0.25)","0 0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.31), 0 9px 18px -8px rgba(0,0,0,0.25)","0 0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.31), 0 10px 20px -8px rgba(0,0,0,0.25)","0 0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.31), 0 11px 20px -8px rgba(0,0,0,0.25)","0 0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.31), 0 12px 22px -8px rgba(0,0,0,0.25)","0 0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.31), 0 13px 22px -8px rgba(0,0,0,0.25)","0 0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.31), 0 14px 24px -8px rgba(0,0,0,0.25)","0 0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.31), 0 16px 28px -8px rgba(0,0,0,0.25)","0 0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.31), 0 18px 30px -8px rgba(0,0,0,0.25)","0 0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.31), 0 20px 32px -8px rgba(0,0,0,0.25)","0 0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.31), 0 22px 34px -8px rgba(0,0,0,0.25)","0 0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.31), 0 24px 36px -8px rgba(0,0,0,0.25)"],"typography":{"h1":{"fontWeight":500,"fontSize":35,"letterSpacing":"-0.24px","fontFamily":"\"Roboto\", \"Helvetica\", \"Arial\", sans-serif","lineHeight":1.167},"h2":{"fontWeight":500,"fontSize":29,"letterSpacing":"-0.24px","fontFamily":"\"Roboto\", \"Helvetica\", \"Arial\", sans-serif","lineHeight":1.2},"h3":{"fontWeight":500,"fontSize":24,"letterSpacing":"-0.06px","fontFamily":"\"Roboto\", \"Helvetica\", \"Arial\", sans-serif","lineHeight":1.167},"h4":{"fontWeight":500,"fontSize":20,"letterSpacing":"-0.06px","fontFamily":"\"Roboto\", \"Helvetica\", \"Arial\", sans-serif","lineHeight":1.235},"h5":{"fontWeight":500,"fontSize":16,"letterSpacing":"-0.05px","fontFamily":"\"Roboto\", \"Helvetica\", \"Arial\", sans-serif","lineHeight":1.334},"h6":{"fontWeight":500,"fontSize":14,"letterSpacing":"-0.05px","fontFamily":"\"Roboto\", \"Helvetica\", \"Arial\", sans-serif","lineHeight":1.6},"overline":{"fontWeight":500,"fontFamily":"\"Roboto\", \"Helvetica\", \"Arial\", sans-serif","fontSize":"0.75rem","lineHeight":2.66,"letterSpacing":"0.08333em","textTransform":"uppercase"},"htmlFontSize":16,"fontFamily":"\"Roboto\", \"Helvetica\", \"Arial\", sans-serif","fontSize":14,"fontWeightLight":300,"fontWeightRegular":400,"fontWeightMedium":500,"fontWeightBold":700,"subtitle1":{"fontFamily":"\"Roboto\", \"Helvetica\", \"Arial\", sans-serif","fontWeight":400,"fontSize":"1rem","lineHeight":1.75,"letterSpacing":"0.00938em"},"subtitle2":{"fontFamily":"\"Roboto\", \"Helvetica\", \"Arial\", sans-serif","fontWeight":500,"fontSize":"0.875rem","lineHeight":1.57,"letterSpacing":"0.00714em"},"body1":{"fontFamily":"\"Roboto\", \"Helvetica\", \"Arial\", sans-serif","fontWeight":400,"fontSize":"1rem","lineHeight":1.5,"letterSpacing":"0.00938em"},"body2":{"fontFamily":"\"Roboto\", \"Helvetica\", \"Arial\", sans-serif","fontWeight":400,"fontSize":"0.875rem","lineHeight":1.43,"letterSpacing":"0.01071em"},"button":{"fontFamily":"\"Roboto\", \"Helvetica\", \"Arial\", sans-serif","fontWeight":500,"fontSize":"0.875rem","lineHeight":1.75,"letterSpacing":"0.02857em","textTransform":"uppercase"},"caption":{"fontFamily":"\"Roboto\", \"Helvetica\", \"Arial\", sans-serif","fontWeight":400,"fontSize":"0.75rem","lineHeight":1.66,"letterSpacing":"0.03333em"},"inherit":{"fontFamily":"inherit","fontWeight":"inherit","fontSize":"inherit","lineHeight":"inherit","letterSpacing":"inherit"}},"unstable_sxConfig":{"border":{"themeKey":"borders"},"borderTop":{"themeKey":"borders"},"borderRight":{"themeKey":"borders"},"borderBottom":{"themeKey":"borders"},"borderLeft":{"themeKey":"borders"},"borderColor":{"themeKey":"palette"},"borderTopColor":{"themeKey":"palette"},"borderRightColor":{"themeKey":"palette"},"borderBottomColor":{"themeKey":"palette"},"borderLeftColor":{"themeKey":"palette"},"outline":{"themeKey":"borders"},"outlineColor":{"themeKey":"palette"},"borderRadius":{"themeKey":"shape.borderRadius"},"color":{"themeKey":"palette"},"bgcolor":{"themeKey":"palette","cssProperty":"backgroundColor"},"backgroundColor":{"themeKey":"palette"},"p":{},"pt":{},"pr":{},"pb":{},"pl":{},"px":{},"py":{},"padding":{},"paddingTop":{},"paddingRight":{},"paddingBottom":{},"paddingLeft":{},"paddingX":{},"paddingY":{},"paddingInline":{},"paddingInlineStart":{},"paddingInlineEnd":{},"paddingBlock":{},"paddingBlockStart":{},"paddingBlockEnd":{},"m":{},"mt":{},"mr":{},"mb":{},"ml":{},"mx":{},"my":{},"margin":{},"marginTop":{},"marginRight":{},"marginBottom":{},"marginLeft":{},"marginX":{},"marginY":{},"marginInline":{},"marginInlineStart":{},"marginInlineEnd":{},"marginBlock":{},"marginBlockStart":{},"marginBlockEnd":{},"displayPrint":{"cssProperty":false},"display":{},"overflow":{},"textOverflow":{},"visibility":{},"whiteSpace":{},"flexBasis":{},"flexDirection":{},"flexWrap":{},"justifyContent":{},"alignItems":{},"alignContent":{},"order":{},"flex":{},"flexGrow":{},"flexShrink":{},"alignSelf":{},"justifyItems":{},"justifySelf":{},"gap":{},"rowGap":{},"columnGap":{},"gridColumn":{},"gridRow":{},"gridAutoFlow":{},"gridAutoColumns":{},"gridAutoRows":{},"gridTemplateColumns":{},"gridTemplateRows":{},"gridTemplateAreas":{},"gridArea":{},"position":{},"zIndex":{"themeKey":"zIndex"},"top":{},"right":{},"bottom":{},"left":{},"boxShadow":{"themeKey":"shadows"},"width":{},"maxWidth":{},"minWidth":{},"height":{},"maxHeight":{},"minHeight":{},"boxSizing":{},"fontFamily":{"themeKey":"typography"},"fontSize":{"themeKey":"typography"},"fontStyle":{"themeKey":"typography"},"fontWeight":{"themeKey":"typography"},"letterSpacing":{},"textTransform":{},"lineHeight":{},"textAlign":{},"typography":{"cssProperty":false,"themeKey":"typography"}},"mixins":{"toolbar":{"minHeight":56,"@media (min-width:0px)":{"@media (orientation: landscape)":{"minHeight":48}},"@media (min-width:600px)":{"minHeight":64}}},"transitions":{"easing":{"easeInOut":"cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1)","easeOut":"cubic-bezier(0.0, 0, 0.2, 1)","easeIn":"cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 1, 1)","sharp":"cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.6, 1)"},"duration":{"shortest":150,"shorter":200,"short":250,"standard":300,"complex":375,"enteringScreen":225,"leavingScreen":195}},"zIndex":{"mobileStepper":1000,"fab":1050,"speedDial":1050,"appBar":1100,"drawer":1200,"modal":1300,"snackbar":1400,"tooltip":1500}}
index-VJueVjK0.js:172 {"breakpoints":{"keys":["xs","sm","md","lg","xl"],"values":{"xs":0,"sm":600,"md":900,"lg":1200,"xl":1536},"unit":"px"},"direction":"ltr","components":{},"palette":{"mode":"light","background":{"default":"#f4f6f8","paper":"#ffffff"},"primary":{"contrastText":"#ffffff","main":"#5664d2","light":"rgb(119, 131, 219)","dark":"rgb(60, 70, 147)"},"text":{"primary":"#172b4d","secondary":"#6b778c","disabled":"rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.38)"},"common":{"black":"#000","white":"#fff"},"secondary":{"main":"#9c27b0","light":"#ba68c8","dark":"#7b1fa2","contrastText":"#fff"},"error":{"main":"#d32f2f","light":"#ef5350","dark":"#c62828","contrastText":"#fff"},"warning":{"main":"#ed6c02","light":"#ff9800","dark":"#e65100","contrastText":"#fff"},"info":{"main":"#0288d1","light":"#03a9f4","dark":"#01579b","contrastText":"#fff"},"success":{"main":"#2e7d32","light":"#4caf50","dark":"#1b5e20","contrastText":"#fff"},"grey":{"50":"#fafafa","100":"#f5f5f5","200":"#eeeeee","300":"#e0e0e0","400":"#bdbdbd","500":"#9e9e9e","600":"#757575","700":"#616161","800":"#424242","900":"#212121","A100":"#f5f5f5","A200":"#eeeeee","A400":"#bdbdbd","A700":"#616161"},"contrastThreshold":3,"tonalOffset":0.2,"divider":"rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12)","action":{"active":"rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.54)","hover":"rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.04)","hoverOpacity":0.04,"selected":"rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08)","selectedOpacity":0.08,"disabled":"rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26)","disabledBackground":"rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12)","disabledOpacity":0.38,"focus":"rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12)","focusOpacity":0.12,"activatedOpacity":0.12}},"shape":{"borderRadius":4},"shadows":["none","0 0 0 1px rgba(63,63,68,0.05), 0 1px 2px 0 rgba(63,63,68,0.15)","0 0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.31), 0 2px 2px -2px rgba(0,0,0,0.25)","0 0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.31), 0 3px 4px -2px rgba(0,0,0,0.25)","0 0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.31), 0 3px 4px -2px rgba(0,0,0,0.25)","0 0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.31), 0 4px 6px -2px rgba(0,0,0,0.25)","0 0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.31), 0 4px 6px -2px rgba(0,0,0,0.25)","0 0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.31), 0 4px 8px -2px rgba(0,0,0,0.25)","0 0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.31), 0 5px 8px -2px rgba(0,0,0,0.25)","0 0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.31), 0 6px 12px -4px rgba(0,0,0,0.25)","0 0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.31), 0 7px 12px -4px rgba(0,0,0,0.25)","0 0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.31), 0 6px 16px -4px rgba(0,0,0,0.25)","0 0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.31), 0 7px 16px -4px rgba(0,0,0,0.25)","0 0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.31), 0 8px 18px -8px rgba(0,0,0,0.25)","0 0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.31), 0 9px 18px -8px rgba(0,0,0,0.25)","0 0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.31), 0 10px 20px -8px rgba(0,0,0,0.25)","0 0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.31), 0 11px 20px -8px rgba(0,0,0,0.25)","0 0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.31), 0 12px 22px -8px rgba(0,0,0,0.25)","0 0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.31), 0 13px 22px -8px rgba(0,0,0,0.25)","0 0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.31), 0 14px 24px -8px rgba(0,0,0,0.25)","0 0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.31), 0 16px 28px -8px rgba(0,0,0,0.25)","0 0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.31), 0 18px 30px -8px rgba(0,0,0,0.25)","0 0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.31), 0 20px 32px -8px rgba(0,0,0,0.25)","0 0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.31), 0 22px 34px -8px rgba(0,0,0,0.25)","0 0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.31), 0 24px 36px -8px rgba(0,0,0,0.25)"],"typography":{"h1":{"fontWeight":500,"fontSize":35,"letterSpacing":"-0.24px","fontFamily":"\"Roboto\", \"Helvetica\", \"Arial\", sans-serif","lineHeight":1.167},"h2":{"fontWeight":500,"fontSize":29,"letterSpacing":"-0.24px","fontFamily":"\"Roboto\", \"Helvetica\", \"Arial\", sans-serif","lineHeight":1.2},"h3":{"fontWeight":500,"fontSize":24,"letterSpacing":"-0.06px","fontFamily":"\"Roboto\", \"Helvetica\", \"Arial\", sans-serif","lineHeight":1.167},"h4":{"fontWeight":500,"fontSize":20,"letterSpacing":"-0.06px","fontFamily":"\"Roboto\", \"Helvetica\", \"Arial\", sans-serif","lineHeight":1.235},"h5":{"fontWeight":500,"fontSize":16,"letterSpacing":"-0.05px","fontFamily":"\"Roboto\", \"Helvetica\", \"Arial\", sans-serif","lineHeight":1.334},"h6":{"fontWeight":500,"fontSize":14,"letterSpacing":"-0.05px","fontFamily":"\"Roboto\", \"Helvetica\", \"Arial\", sans-serif","lineHeight":1.6},"overline":{"fontWeight":500,"fontFamily":"\"Roboto\", \"Helvetica\", \"Arial\", sans-serif","fontSize":"0.75rem","lineHeight":2.66,"letterSpacing":"0.08333em","textTransform":"uppercase"},"htmlFontSize":16,"fontFamily":"\"Roboto\", \"Helvetica\", \"Arial\", sans-serif","fontSize":14,"fontWeightLight":300,"fontWeightRegular":400,"fontWeightMedium":500,"fontWeightBold":700,"subtitle1":{"fontFamily":"\"Roboto\", \"Helvetica\", \"Arial\", sans-serif","fontWeight":400,"fontSize":"1rem","lineHeight":1.75,"letterSpacing":"0.00938em"},"subtitle2":{"fontFamily":"\"Roboto\", \"Helvetica\", \"Arial\", sans-serif","fontWeight":500,"fontSize":"0.875rem","lineHeight":1.57,"letterSpacing":"0.00714em"},"body1":{"fontFamily":"\"Roboto\", \"Helvetica\", \"Arial\", sans-serif","fontWeight":400,"fontSize":"1rem","lineHeight":1.5,"letterSpacing":"0.00938em"},"body2":{"fontFamily":"\"Roboto\", \"Helvetica\", \"Arial\", sans-serif","fontWeight":400,"fontSize":"0.875rem","lineHeight":1.43,"letterSpacing":"0.01071em"},"button":{"fontFamily":"\"Roboto\", \"Helvetica\", \"Arial\", sans-serif","fontWeight":500,"fontSize":"0.875rem","lineHeight":1.75,"letterSpacing":"0.02857em","textTransform":"uppercase"},"caption":{"fontFamily":"\"Roboto\", \"Helvetica\", \"Arial\", sans-serif","fontWeight":400,"fontSize":"0.75rem","lineHeight":1.66,"letterSpacing":"0.03333em"},"inherit":{"fontFamily":"inherit","fontWeight":"inherit","fontSize":"inherit","lineHeight":"inherit","letterSpacing":"inherit"}},"unstable_sxConfig":{"border":{"themeKey":"borders"},"borderTop":{"themeKey":"borders"},"borderRight":{"themeKey":"borders"},"borderBottom":{"themeKey":"borders"},"borderLeft":{"themeKey":"borders"},"borderColor":{"themeKey":"palette"},"borderTopColor":{"themeKey":"palette"},"borderRightColor":{"themeKey":"palette"},"borderBottomColor":{"themeKey":"palette"},"borderLeftColor":{"themeKey":"palette"},"outline":{"themeKey":"borders"},"outlineColor":{"themeKey":"palette"},"borderRadius":{"themeKey":"shape.borderRadius"},"color":{"themeKey":"palette"},"bgcolor":{"themeKey":"palette","cssProperty":"backgroundColor"},"backgroundColor":{"themeKey":"palette"},"p":{},"pt":{},"pr":{},"pb":{},"pl":{},"px":{},"py":{},"padding":{},"paddingTop":{},"paddingRight":{},"paddingBottom":{},"paddingLeft":{},"paddingX":{},"paddingY":{},"paddingInline":{},"paddingInlineStart":{},"paddingInlineEnd":{},"paddingBlock":{},"paddingBlockStart":{},"paddingBlockEnd":{},"m":{},"mt":{},"mr":{},"mb":{},"ml":{},"mx":{},"my":{},"margin":{},"marginTop":{},"marginRight":{},"marginBottom":{},"marginLeft":{},"marginX":{},"marginY":{},"marginInline":{},"marginInlineStart":{},"marginInlineEnd":{},"marginBlock":{},"marginBlockStart":{},"marginBlockEnd":{},"displayPrint":{"cssProperty":false},"display":{},"overflow":{},"textOverflow":{},"visibility":{},"whiteSpace":{},"flexBasis":{},"flexDirection":{},"flexWrap":{},"justifyContent":{},"alignItems":{},"alignContent":{},"order":{},"flex":{},"flexGrow":{},"flexShrink":{},"alignSelf":{},"justifyItems":{},"justifySelf":{},"gap":{},"rowGap":{},"columnGap":{},"gridColumn":{},"gridRow":{},"gridAutoFlow":{},"gridAutoColumns":{},"gridAutoRows":{},"gridTemplateColumns":{},"gridTemplateRows":{},"gridTemplateAreas":{},"gridArea":{},"position":{},"zIndex":{"themeKey":"zIndex"},"top":{},"right":{},"bottom":{},"left":{},"boxShadow":{"themeKey":"shadows"},"width":{},"maxWidth":{},"minWidth":{},"height":{},"maxHeight":{},"minHeight":{},"boxSizing":{},"fontFamily":{"themeKey":"typography"},"fontSize":{"themeKey":"typography"},"fontStyle":{"themeKey":"typography"},"fontWeight":{"themeKey":"typography"},"letterSpacing":{},"textTransform":{},"lineHeight":{},"textAlign":{},"typography":{"cssProperty":false,"themeKey":"typography"}},"mixins":{"toolbar":{"minHeight":56,"@media (min-width:0px)":{"@media (orientation: landscape)":{"minHeight":48}},"@media (min-width:600px)":{"minHeight":64}}},"transitions":{"easing":{"easeInOut":"cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1)","easeOut":"cubic-bezier(0.0, 0, 0.2, 1)","easeIn":"cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 1, 1)","sharp":"cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.6, 1)"},"duration":{"shortest":150,"shorter":200,"short":250,"standard":300,"complex":375,"enteringScreen":225,"leavingScreen":195}},"zIndex":{"mobileStepper":1000,"fab":1050,"speedDial":1050,"appBar":1100,"drawer":1200,"modal":1300,"snackbar":1400,"tooltip":1500}}
```

Seems I don't have function defined :s

Comment: It sounds like `functions` is `undefined`.  When you debug, what does `theme` contain?

Comment: [^^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77806223/cannot-destruture-property-linergradiant-of-r-as-it-is-undefined#comment137166071_77806223) More: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/ Also, debug using a development/debug build, not a production build, so your variable names aren't minified.

Comment: Maybe a missing prop ?

Answer (score 0):

I restart my app from scratch, and I fixed my issue